# Is Sensation Seeking Still a Thing?

Tags: sensation

The first time I read an article, which offered me a high level basic understanding of a behavioral model called [sensation seeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking), changed the way I look at world since. This was the first time I'd found myself so enamoured by such a simplistic concept, which was so easy to relate to my behavior, and provided me with a means of learning how my mind works.

A Sensation Seeker is loosely defined as an individual who consistently feels a yearning to engage in high energy, high risk, and high adrenaline rush. They are known to be sexually promiscuous, thrill seekers, and/or skofflaws.

Is the cognitive phenomenon known as Sensation Seeking still the designation for this behavior? If not, has the condition been renamed?